# Why render result of animation is black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a 3D text with smoke simulation on it. It's all baked up and ready. As you can see on the screenshot the 3D smoke effect is "baked" and the flames are visible in 3d Viewport while in *Rendered* shading mode.

However when I render the animation every frame turns out to be blank, no text or anything.

Why is the rendered animation black instead of showing text with smoke simulation on it ?

[image]

Please download the blend file here and inspect, and some tips would be greatly apreciated: https://app.box.com/s/fih3vv6smnfjazcrmjlagothcja3ffly

thanks in advance!
Danny

Comment: This is due to the film transparency (film section in the render panel). But for now I have not found a way to keep film transparency and having the text rendered. Do you need this transparency ?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles.

Comment: Lemon, thanks! I solved it with your help!