# Glare Not Showing in Render

Tags: compositing-nodes

When I add a glare in compositing it doesn't show on the actual render. Is there something I'm missing? I've tried using different paths to put the glare through but that just turns the while screen white. Help?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your node setup?

Comment: [This question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57816/2217) should help you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. No one else but you knows hows what paths you've used or how you've set up your scene, nodes, output, etc, etc.... How can we help you then?

Comment: NVM guys lol. I got it