# Cycles - glare/bloom isn't working?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes

Ok, Im very new to nodes with the actual render but Im trying to do what these people did, just get a basic glow around my emissive materials: unity animate object transform into another [How do I get the Glare node to output transparent instead of Black background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background)

Maybe Im not understanding something basic but here's my node setup:

[image]

And, both just in viewport when I hit Render and then when I actually render out an image, nothing is remotely glowing:

[image]

those image planes are emissive - they aren't glowing any more than before. Whats wrong herE?

Comment: Hello, I actually dont really know whats going on here as it seems that you have everything set up correctly. Try adding a simple sphere or plane into the scene and setting up with emitter properties, then see if the glare works on a raw object rather then the image. or try checking your layers and scenes and making sure everything is aligned there. Good luck.

Comment: other node effects work, like an RGB curve..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Here I created an example Scene with your node Setup (without any glowing effects)]
Here I created an example Scene with your node Setup (without any glowing effects)

[image: Here I just switched the positions at of the input the Alpha-over node and then it worked]
Here I just switched the positions at of the input the Alpha-over node and then it worked

Comment: Also work in Blender 2.8 beta.

Comment: Why do we need the alpha over node? Doesn't the glare node already mix the original image with the fog-glowed one? In other words, the output of the glare node is identical to the output of the alpha over node?

Comment: you don‘t necessarily need it but I wanted to build my example as close as possible to the question of the original poster