# Is it possible to see glare streaks in transparent areas too?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Attached you see my problem. Is it possible to see the glare FX in the transparent areas "outside" the rendered content too?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background

Comment: This solution worked perfect for me:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77940/15678

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that worked perfect for me. Seperating and mixing one glare color channel with glare alpha output works great and supports nearly all situations, even for other FX nodes.

Here the node tree:

[image]

And the file:

[image]