# How can I render out Objects with Transparents but without Background?

Tags: rendering, transparency

I want to render out only the trail that I can composite it individually.
So when I render it out without a Background -> Transparent Background, then my Trail looks grey and is really hard to see.
I hope you can help me out it is really important for me to know how to fix it.[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your outliner?

Comment: Did you maybe select an output file format that does not support transparency, such as JPG?

Comment: The information is there, but the render viewer has an old bug, where it cannot show emissive and transparent pixels (it doesn't show associated alpha correctly) read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824