# Strugging to render my fire animation with Alpha/Transparency correctly

Tags: transparency, osx, fire

i've made a little fire animation using the particle system that i'm happy with, but i'm really struggling to output it correctly as a 4second .Mov with alpha/transparency enabled so i can import it into another NLE.

I'm making sure that i'm using a codec with RGBA enabled (I've tried them all now) in a Quicktime container.

Whatever I do, the fire looks fine...but the background stays black/non-transparent.

I then discovered the film/transparent checkbox in the render tab. This fixes the transparency, but now all the Orange colour/glow has gone from the fire, & i'm left with something that looks like grey smoke (see screen grab)

I'm new to Blender, but if someone could talk me through what I need to check/uncheck to make this render correctly, I'd very much appreciate it.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824

Answer (score 3):

Blender’s viewer is and always has been broken with regard to alpha encoding displaying correctly.

Apply your rendered fire plane to an alpha over, and you’ll see the emissive yet unoccluding fire return.

Again, Blender’s viewer is and has been totally broken for a decade.

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't understand . Are you saying that the render is fine, but how i display it after its imported is the key? Ive imported my fire render back into a blender composition (image as a plane) with the usual AlphaBlend option, & its still looks grey.

Comment: If you render it, composite it with an Alpha Over. If you need to save the file, you must use EXR or it won’t save correctly. Does that help?

Comment: Oh. So there's no way to export not-broken PNG sequences from Blender...

Comment: Correct. PNG is a broken format by design.