# Problem with Rendering Candle Flame with RGBA transparency

Tags: rendering, shaders, light, transparency

I have a problem and I can not find an answer in internet. So  basically I have a candle with animated candle flame (made with texture nodes and I added a point light source) and I want to render only the flame animation, because other things are static, and then combine the static image with the animated. So I need candle flame to be with a RGBA information. However, when I render it, it gives very weird result.
So this is how it looks in my viewport:

[image]

And this is how it looks while rendering:

[image]

And it is the same in Cycles or Eevee. Could someone please tell how to fix that, if it is even possible?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154188/strugging-to-render-my-fire-animation-with-alpha-transparency-correctly/154213#154213

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background/44148#44148

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/164940#164940

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=viewer+is+broken

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this should work properly in 2.91.

Comment: Hello! Yes, so working with OpenEXR worked like a charm. OpenEXR is not so handy format though, for me. And then I downloaded 2.91 it seemed that it works with PNG as well, at least in render viewport. But when I saved it in PNG, it was again weird. So, I guess, just need to stick to the OpenEXR then.

Comment: Wanted to add more, that simply putting all this together in video editing mode gave me weird shapes around the flame. So I worked it out in compositing editor, where I added image sequence of flames and my static image together with MixRGB add mode. Be aware, that the alpha tick should be unchecked in composite end node. At least with it checked it gave me weird look.

Comment: PNG is a terrible format, it can't deal with associated alpha: It will not allow you to have pixels that are emissive and transparent at the same time.

Comment: To composite over a background the correct operation is "Alpha over", so use an Alpha Over node, as pointed out on the links in the comments.