# Refections on transparent object - renderd view diffrent to render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, glass, reflection

Hi I'm staggering with a problem. I made PET Bottles with a Principled BSDF Node. The Material looks nice in **rendered view** but not in the **final render**. I'm loosing a lot of the light source reflection on the transparent part.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

[image: Nodesetup/Renderd View]

[image: Final Render]

Comment: Maybe try reducing "Filter Glossy" under Caustics. It increases the roughness of the reflections to reduce fireflies, but can dull the look of things. Start with 0.5 and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Sadly no different result. Lowering it to 0.01 gets me some fireflies the conveyor. But worth a try, thx

Comment: Strange, not sure why that's happening. I tried to recreate with the settings you have (showing), and I could not. Any chance you could post a minimal .blend file?

Comment: https://we.tl/t-vl353UYkhG  even a new blend file and recreating the shader didn't help. There must be totally messed up setting I can't find :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old bug in blender. You are doing nothing wrong. The information is there, but the render window is not displaying it correctly. It cannot display pixels that are transparent and luminous at the same time. Glares, glows, reflections. and fire don't display correctly.

View your image just as color (not color and alpha)

[image]

Your information should be there. To save it use a format like OpenEXR

For more info read:

[How do I get the Glare node to output transparent instead of Black background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824)