# Blender Eevee how to render Bloom effect when using transparent background

Tags: eevee-render-engine, effects, transparency

I need to render Bloom effect while using a transparent background, I need to save PNG sequence with RGBA, when I do this, the Bloom effect is being removed by the transparency since it falls outside the geometry.
[image]
This is the effect I'm after but with transparent background.
[image]
This is what I'm getting out of the box when enabling transparent.
**My question is:** How can I keep the Bloom effect overlay while rendering with a transparent background?

Comment: Save as Open EXR, emissive light is still there. To make it visible just add some background https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh9vz.png (originally from this post https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a workaround with compositing:
1- Enable Bloom pass in View Layer before rendering
[image]
2- In Compositor, Add the Bloom pass to the Alpha of the image, use a ColorRamp node to control the bloom effect, and to convert it at the same time to black and white.
[image: The original Alpha]
Check the original Alpha in the image above and compare to the next image with Bloom added via the ColorRamp node.
[image]
3- now we need to use the outcome as the new Alpha pass instead of the original one, for that, I used a Select Alpha node, linked the original image color pass to the color, the new alpha pass to the alpha.
[image: Bloom effect with transparent background]
You can see here how the bloom effect shows on the transparent background, now I can fiddle with the ColorRamp node to get the better result, but I find it easier to temporarily add a background in the compositor using an Alpha Over node, to see the results, then I can remove before final render. I also need to mention that I found it gives better results when I use "Ease" mode in the ColorRamp node, but this depends on the desired effect and the project at hand.
[image: Adding the background in the compositor to check the results]

Comment: Also, remember to set `Set Alpha`'s mode to `Replace Alpha` instead of `Apply Mask` from Blender 2.92.