# Problem with array modifier, incorrect orientation and deformation

Tags: modifiers

I am having some issues with this file I am adding. I want to place the cube around this ring but the cube is being deformed (stretched along the larger radius) also the face orientation is wrong. I don't understand what wrong am doing.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

link>>>>  https://drive.google.com/file/d/18bmQSoUdcYCo3ynGP01CEFIM2MGSswCA/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to apply the scale of your bezier circle with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. Once done don't forget to correct the vertices radius, given that applying scale will change the vertices radius up to the former scale value (go into *Edit* mode, select the bezier vertices and in the *N* panel bring back the *Mean Radius* to 1):

[image]

But anyway, *Array + Curve* modifiers always deform your object at least a bit, if you don't want it to be deformed you need to use another method like instances on vertices or particles. In the latest versions the *Geometry Node Editor* is even more flexible.

Comment: hi, thanks for responding, I did apply  (but not as you have shown I just did CTRL A)the transform and scale but that was ruining the curve, plus there is no such option as you are showing.(probably, I have already applied  thus its not showing.) Is there any way to fit the boxes to certain positions of that toroid? without manual vertex groups? I want to use those separately(independently) with different materials so I didn't use particles now I think there is no easy way :-( .. Thanks anyway. I will go for manual :).

Comment: yes applying the scale is Ctrl A, then you need to go in Edit mode, select all and open the N panel (press N to display it) to correct the vertices radius), then you need to give some corrections to the cube's Array modifier values to locate the cube where you want precisely

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt notice that I have to go inside edit mode sorry.....

Comment: can You do me a favour !! can you pleas answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664159/blender-grease-pencils-glow-effect-in-any-specific-layer-or-region

Comment: what part of stackexchange is it? didn't you ask in Blender Stack Exchange? To create blur and bloom: in Cycles you can limit blur to the object you want with the Compositor, in Eevee you can do the same. For the Eevee Bloom effect specifically, it looks like you can also use the Compositor, see the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200068/blender-eevee-how-to-render-bloom-effect-when-using-transparent-background

Comment: I wasn't aware of dedicated blender stack then. I didn't remove as people may find that helpful. I was asking in regards of grease pencil only. I am aware (still I don't know enough) of the passes and compositor, thank you I will certainly check it out.

Comment: oh ok I thought it would work the same with GP, no? Yes maybe ask the question here, you'll have more answers I guess

Comment: I have been working with grease pencil from a very long time but unfortunately this is a real problem that hinders productivity, there is only one solution, which I have mentioned , I will certainly post it here.