# Exporting animation with emission loses its glow work in After effects

Tags: animation, node-editor, emission

I have an animation which has emission, when it renders using EEVEE, it seems fine, but when I import the animation sequence(PNG) into after effects, there is no glow.

This is my node setup :

[image]

This is how it looks in Blender and After Effects :

[image]

As you can see, there is a glow in Blender but not in AE.

What do I need to do?

Here is the Blend File [image]

Comment: Try to change the blend mode. Or export your png over black background (no transparency) and set it to screen in AE

Comment: This is my node set up simple emission: https://ibb.co/MPgkG8x

I didn't understand the black background with no transparency, can you do a screen shot please.

Comment: Actually that wouldn't work with the black background because the emission shader is also affecting other objects in the scene giving them some tint highlights.

Comment: Ok, may be I misunderstood you. Can you post screenshots of your scene and your AE composition so I can understand your problem better? A pic of your render and a pic of how it looks like in AE

Comment: Here's the screen shot, and I also provide the blender file too.

https://ibb.co/Jj3Zm59

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=NwzdVD9g" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NwzdVD9g/)

Comment: I see, it's because Blender doesn't render the bloom's alpha. There is a workaround here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200068/blender-eevee-how-to-render-bloom-effect-when-using-transparent-background

Comment: I have followed the tutorial connected the nodes (Checked on BLOOM) , but when I import in AE its still with no glow: https://ibb.co/0XGnwZV

Comment: Can you upload the modified file? It should have worked

Comment: an easy way, render a video with [only the bloom pass](https://ibb.co/G0x5rZh), then in after effects mix it with screen or add mode

Comment: Here's the Blender file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=aDz6VSAz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aDz6VSAz/)

Comment: make your 'color ramp' wider, set the 'set alpha' node to 'replace alpha', in after effects interpret as premultiplied with black... try those things, or just export the bloom as a video and composite as add or screen in after effect, you get more control and is easy, I've done it before

Comment: That did the trick, replaced Alpha which I had missed and widen the color ramp. Thank you.