# Transparent background and volume emission (cycles)

Tags: rendering, transparency, volumetrics, emission

I am new to Blender and am having troubles rendering a Sun.

The layers I created as volume emissions for the atmosphere are not exporting properly on a transparent background as PNG.

On the render result window I can see the atmosphere, but when it's saved to my pc all I get it is the object.

EDIT: This question was marked too similar to one where the glare node is creating a black background but my image successfully renders with transparent background.

Anyone know what I should do?[image: 1st image is render result second image is the image as it's saved on my computer][image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200068/blender-eevee-how-to-render-bloom-effect-when-using-transparent-background https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222837/blender-does-not-set-the-alpha-channel-correctly