Render window and final image is different
Render window and image output is missing objects. So i have laser object and is not there in the final output. 


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222837/blender-does-not-set-the-alpha-channel-correctly  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272917/transparent-emissive-objects-glow-effect-not-visible-in-rendered-output-files/272919#272919 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173932/exr-color-difference-to-png https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205911/glare-on-transparent-background-using-cycles
