# Cycles - Transparent Glass Alpha Clipping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, glass

I'm having an issue with Cycles in Blender 2.91.0.

I have Film>Transparent>Transparent Glass checked in the Render Properties Panel.

In the Render Result window I get this, which looks like it's supposed to. The glass is visible, but transparent where it needs to be.

[image]

When I save it as a PNG or view it in the Compositor, all the transparent zones are clipped out. Anything below a certain threshold of transparency just gets removed.

[image]

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Images are very small, so it is hard to see. A guess: could be transparency or transmission depth in the light path rendering settings.

Comment: @lemon there's not a whole lot to see beyond what's readily apparent in the images. I'll take a look at the light path settings

Comment: It is hard to help you with the current information on the question. Please [edit] the question and add more information.

Comment: @susu what information is missing? I included all relevant information.

Comment: It is up to you to share information or not [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) But here is an idea: Don't use png. Png cannot deal with associated alpha information. Also try updating to blender 2.92 to display the alpha channel correctly on the compositor's viewport. Save the image as EXR. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824

Comment: @susu dude really? Of course it's up to me, and I included all the relevant information about Blender version, file type, and the issue at hand! If there's information you think is missing please tell me what that is so I can include it! 

However, thank you for the relevant information, I believe that has at least partially answered my question, though I'll need to investigate a bit further to be sure.