# Cycles Fire + smoke png renders save empty

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, smoke-simulation, fire, mantaflow

I am rendering 2 different fire + smoke simulations with seemingly the exact same settings. One saves to PNG with alpha perfectly. The other seems to render properly but the saved png is blank.

After 2 days of wrestling with this I figured its time to get help.

I am using Blender version 2.92 on a PC with Windows 10.

here is the nodes for the smoke fire domain. the same for each one

[image: fire domain nodes]

This is how the working render looks.

[image]

here is the render screen for the one that saves blank.

[image]

Here is the working png

[image]

And the non working png

[image]

Here is the scene setup and render settings for each

[image]

I really hope someone can point me in the right direction, I am at a total loss at this point to figure out why one works fine and the other gives a blank png.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think what you can see on first image is non emisive part of Sim -smoke the rest that is invisible is emisive part, the second image probably consist only from emissive light, try to composite. Check this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214 ... Also from description it seems more like differences in save method so check output setup or enabled Compositor with disconnected node.

Comment: I have tried to dial up the smoke factor in the non functional one but it made no difference. the output setups are identical on both files.

Comment: Double check the fire and smoke settings in the domain and in the emitter. Try changing the emission mode from “geometry“ to “outflow“ if it is that way.

Comment: PNGs are a broken format with broken alpha encoding. They don’t work and were designed by idiots apparently. Use EXR.

Comment: please provide the blend file