# Blender is rendering all file formats with transpancy as boxes without the rest of the image

Tags: rendering, transparency

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DjGpppAUfI) to render fire. But, for some reason when I render the images, any image format with transparency just shows a box instead of the image. I can render the image with a background, but not without one. Any idea what would cause this, and how I can fix it? I'm using blender 2.92 by the way.

[image]

It should look like this, minus the background.

[image]

Edit: Here's the blender file: [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, this behaviour is quite normal when you have emissive transparency over transparent background.

Comment: if you don't want this question to be closed you should answer quicker...the moderators are quick and hard here. Do you render in eevee or cycles?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: you are right, but he is a beginner. He doesn't know what he does ( (as we all, when we started, although lots of people have forgotten this). And if we can show him in his file what he can change ...maybe he can solve it. And if he didn't make it to follow the tutorial...he is obviously not watching very carefully ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm working nights next week, so I slept late today. I added my blender file to the post. Thanks for any help! @Chris, I rendered with eevee I believe.

Answer (score 0):

just hide your plane in viewport + render.

[image]

and you will get this:

[image]

i just added an alpha over node with green to your compositing tree so that you can see that the alpha is "there".

[image]