# Is it possible to get the Compositor File Output image sequence to match the Rendered video?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I've done some basic Compositing starting with a sequence of EXR files. All I put was a Glare Node, Composite output, and File Output. In the Compositor I set the file output to PNG and specified a folder. The Composite Node uses the main Blender Output Properties rendering an MKV file which is saved in a different folder so we keeps things separate. After Ctrl+F12 I get both the PNG sequence and the video file but only the video file has the Compositing applied. The PNG sequence looks just like the original EXR sequence. What am I missing?

Edit: A screenshot of my Compositor Nodes
[image]

Comment: can you provide blend file?

Comment: Make sure the glare node is connected to the file output node.

Comment: I added a screenshot. @brockmann Node connections where the first thing I checked. I've been trying different things, videos, and web searches all seem to indicate that I'm doing it right. This is Blender 2.9 if that matters.

Comment: You're rendering PNG files, so semi-transparent glare doesn't show up over transparent background. Check these questions: [Fire over transparent background 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles), [Fire over transparent background 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221860/blender-is-rendering-all-file-formats-with-transpancy-as-boxes-without-the-rest) and this one [Glare over transparent background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you. That pointed me in the right direction. I appreciate your time and expertise. I've been struggling with this for a few days before asking so I'm glad to be on the path to a solution finally.