# Blender motion blur on alpha channel

Tags: compositing-nodes

I’ve added motion blur to my object in compositing and it has registered on RGB channels but not the alpha channel. So when I export my image the blur outside the RGB channels of the object is lost. I’m not too sure how to solve this. I’ve attached an image showing how it looks in view port to how it looks once I’ve saved the image.

[image: How it saves out, without the blur]

Comment: I didn't test it, but if you see motion blur in channels it is probably the same system as for emissions see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214

Comment: @vklidu thank you, I managed to fix the issue in the end, but the link you sent looks like it could also have fixed it :)

Comment: Great :) ... If you found solution don't hesitate to answer your Q ... this site is meant to be a knowledge base ... so go ahead :)

Comment: I made the mistake of using a mix node rather than an alpha over node which was why my alpha channel for the blur wasn't showing :) As soon as I used alpha over it sorted my problem :)