# Blender renders smoke in preview but smoke not in video or image file?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, smoke-simulation

I am rendering smoke, and all seems well until I open the output file in Premier Pro or Photoshop.  The liquid in the glass renders (the smoke renders inside the glass) but as soon as the smoke leaves the glass jar,(even though it appears in a bake and render window) the smoke does not appear in the output files (.png and .mov)

Can anybody help?

[image: Render view window]
[[image: Video render in Premier pro][2]]
[image: Domain material]
[image: Output settings]
[image: Smoke emetter settings]

Comment: I know the reason why this happens but I don't know how it can be fixed :/

Comment: Have you set cache type to final and baked it?

Comment: yes baked- it seems to be something to do with the Alpha channel for the transparent background.  RGBA when I switch output file to RGB - the smoke appears, but now I have the problem of green smoke from croma key!  Would be great if I could work out how to keep a transparent video but still have green smoke?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214