# Can someone explain how this glowing cube was achieved?

Tags: texturing, theme

First Post! I'm talking about the glowing cube. Pic taken from a video tutorial and they used a theme to get the result, but what I don't understand is how they got this in blender render and achieved this. can anyone help or point me in the right direction? I've been trying to get this for hours now.

[image]

Comment: hello, you can use the Glare node, or another kind of filter, in the Compositor

Comment: blender 2.9x  ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214 ... or enable "Bloom" under Eevee engine Properties.