# Blender result and saved image different

Tags: rendering, animation, particles, transparency, color

[image]

The render result and the saved image are different in how the particles are showing up. If I remove alpha, it appears just fine. Why is alpha being present changing the particles?

Comment: I guess it's just the way your image viewer renders the image with alpha channel. Have you tried to open the image in another Blender file ?

Comment: as @mqbakamqbaka suggest this is probably the case... in the render view, your background is transparent and you see semi-transparent white particles very sharp and nice... but when you open it in image viewer your transparent background is black... due to particles being semi-transparent yellow pixels, what happens if you mix them with black background? They fade away a bit...

Comment: @Jeffrey Part that is invisible is emission (glare) over transparent bg, but it should be invisible in preview as well until you add background or disable alpha https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214 ... what version of blender you use? I expect you use compositor Glare too, right?

Comment: did you try to render to exr?