# Rendering bloom with transparent when animating

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I'm trying to render a spinning logo with bloom and a transparent background, but when I add the image sequence to the video editor, the bloom no longer shows and the logo becomes lighter.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/164940#164940