# Transparency shader causing problems (Viewport render different than final render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, transparency, shaders

I've set up a shader to render a fire/explosion looking material, which ended up quite good when rendering in the **viewport**. When I hit the render button it looks completely different and I am convinced it has something to do with the **transparency**, but I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've attached some screenshots to make it easier to understand what exactly is happening. Here is some additional information (if it makes any difference):

- using Blender 2.78b
- using Filmig Log Encoding Base color management
- using a hair particle system which creates multiple transparency layers
- using Cycles render engine
- rendering on GPU

Thank you for all answers in advance!

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: This is a known limitation of the render viewport. Most likely your image is fine, but the blender cannot display it. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background/44148#44148 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824 Evaluate your image using RGB display (Not RGBA): https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAoxU.png

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! You were right. When I'm using a black instead of a transparent background everything is fine.

Comment: If you use blender to composite this image on top of a background image you will have no problems. If you are intending to do the compositing in other software then  avoid the PNG format, use OpenEXR instead.