# Glare and transparency

Tags: compositing-nodes

So I did add Glare in Compositing mode and when I render, it works as it should.

But when I try to render it with transparent background, it's not working. Why?

Comment: Some screenshots would be helpful to answer your question. However, my initial guess is that even though the Glare might actually be working, the original alpha is still being used for final output and therefore cuts off the Glare.

Comment: it is likely that you are doing nothing wrong. **There is a bug on the viewer for the compositor** . Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/glow-effect-invisible-on-transparent-background?rq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles

Comment: Read also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background/44148#44148

Answer (score 3):

To see the glare in action, I would do this:

[image]

So the glare is working, but it doesn't affect the alpha channel. To make it do so, I'm setting the mix value to 1 to make the node output *only* the glare. I'm adding the glow to the image and the alpha, so it will be part of the alpha channel too. I'm then recombining them with a *set alpha* node.

Remember to clamp the add on the alpha, as it should never be greater than 1 (or smaller than 0)

I hope this helps you :D

Comment: Holy moly... I've read hundreds of resources and tried dozens of solutions... only this one worked... I very much appreciate it, dear @Uanpis Cardada