# Glare Transparency Correct in Render, but lost in save to PNG

Tags: rendering, transparency, compositing-nodes, file-format

I know this is a tired problem, but the solutions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97006/glare-and-transparency?noredirect=1&lq=1) aren't working for me so I'm posting here. I'm using blender 2.92.0. In the compositor I have a Render Layers Node going into a Glare node, and the Glare node into the Composite node with "Use Alpha" checked. On the left is the blender render with glare, on the right is the saved .png where the glare is lost in the transparency. I want the image to look like the render. Is this to do with premultiplication or something?

I tried the other node configurations from the aforementioned posts, and all of them produce similar results with a functioning render and a malfunctioning png.

[image: glare and transparency.]

Comment: Hello :). Yes, PNG cannot save both emmisive and transparent pixels. It a limitation of the format, use EXR instead.

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: @Chris You always write that ;) But it's a waste of server space when it's clearly image format limitations that can be experienced by anyone with similar setup. Jachym's link provides the best solution.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann : well...you have 20 years+ Blender experience and see this. I only have a few month experience. So I often fiddle around with the blend file to find a solution.maybe in 2 or 3 years an image is enough for me too. 

Comment: Thanks y'all, @JachymMichal yeah EXR is a lot better, still some issues with color backgrounds around the border of the letters, but at least the glare is there. I had tried the EXR, but was previewing in gimp where I couldn't make out the glare. Looks alright in blender though