# Strange white line artifact in smoke simulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, artifacts, fire

I am using a fire simulation on a match in front of a green plane which I am hoping will act as a green screen so that I can composite it on top of a white background however I am now getting strange white artefacts showing up in the render. [image]

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the Blender file, if possible.

Question: Why are you not rendering this by using an alpha channel image file format instead of a green screen background?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but a question to your methodology. You don't need green. Green is used when generating images on a camera, since you cannot generate alpha channels directly in the real world. But for CG you can generate the matte (alpha or transparency) directly. Why generate a background just to remove it later?

Comment: I had trouble using the RGBA with my simulation as every time I did it would remove the fire. If you could talk me through how to get that to work then that would be just as good. Thank you.

Comment: All you need is a transparent background and save as EXR  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background **and** https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles **and this one too:** https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57824/92768

Comment: Oh ok, thank you, but just out of interest do you know why there are the strange lines?