# Blender 2.83.4 Eevee viewport color and rendered color are different with transparency

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Having an issue with rendering png, movie files or any render with transparency.  What I want from the Eevee display viewport render and actually rendering the animation or screen render give me vastly different results. The picture attached will show the color on the left around the model is green (left) and correct blue (right).

If I disable the transparency from the render properties panel under film I get what I'm looking for. The Blender Render is wrong.[image]

Comment: Can you upload your file and add a link in the question?

Answer (score 1):

> *display viewport render* is OK

> *If I disable the transparency from the render properties panel under film I get what I'm looking for*.

The viewer for the render image is broken and has been broken for a long time.It cannot display luminous pixels that are transparent at the same time.

PNG is a format that can't do that either. It cannot do **associated alpha** channel correctly.

If you look at the rendered image as color (not color+A)

[image]

Or add a black backround and use alpha over to composite you the image over it and you should see if the render is correct.

As for saving the image, save as EXR and everything should be fine.

More info:

[Rendering fire animations with transparent background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background/44148#44148)

[Render semi-transparent volume with cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles)

and

[How do I get the Glare node to output transparent instead of Black background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824)

Comment: Thank you for an answer.  I clicked a couple of the links.  Tried that and also re-rendered using EXR (same results).  So you are saying that Transparency doesn't work correctly at all??   I can't seem to get what I'm looking for out in a render.

Comment: Transparency works, but the viewer has problems displaying emissive and transparent pixels. PNG also cannot store those pixels either .

Comment: Wow...Thank you for the reply.  I guess I don't need to report that bug eh?  Yes, I can get the transparency to render but color and even the alpha is not correct.  Wow...huge bug.  Game changer for me for this project.  Any other ideas on how I can get this to render correctly?  Thanks again for responding!!

Comment: Please edit your question and add a link to your file so that others can inspect it and help out.

Comment: If I render a 16bit .Tiff, EXR Full Float, Multi EXR full float, I get a proper render.  Everything else with a alpha, (movie, png, or .tga etc) will not render correctly.  I have to go to the saved file on the hard drive to actually see it there.  The render window always displays it wrong.

Comment: EXR supports associated alpha. Formats that use unassociated alpha will not  represent those luminous and transparent pixels correctly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#:~:text=If%20an%20alpha%20channel%20is,or%20pixel%2C%20disregarding%20its%20opacity. If you are rendering with the intent of further processing or compositing, EXR is the right format to use.