# Fire not rendering as shown in renderview (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mantaflow

my problem is that the final image is very different from what i see in the renderview. Im new to cycles (blender in general) so i guess it could be some render settings im not quite familiar. Anyone could help me find out what?
Update: the issue disappears when i render it out without a transparent background. Still not solved since i need to composite it and it being with an alpha channel is essential
[image: Renderview x final image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44148/29586 What version of Blender are you using as that answer does indicate that the problem should be fixed after 2.92