# principled Volume is visible in the render result but not in the saved picture

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

I can see the volume in the render result but when I open the png image in Photos it's invisible

[image: Render]

[image: Saved Picture]

Comment: Did you use different layers? Compositing? Maybe you want to provide your blend file?

Comment: Similar question:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background

Comment: also here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32900/how-to-properly-render-smoke-on-a-transparent-background
and here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles

Comment: As I read in other posts I think it is a problem of the volume emission, that can't be saved as a PNG since it count than as blank pixels do you guys know a way to use PNG without removing the transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

Use Volume scatter instead of principle Volume....You need to adjust your setting but it work. Add an emission shader and a mix shader ;)