VDB volume is shown in Render Window, but not in the rendered image
I'm trying to render an animation that involves a VDB volume. I'm exporting as PNG in EEVEE and made the background transparent, and when I choose Render Animation, I can clearly see the VDB volume in the render window, but when I open the rendered PNGs, the volume is completely transparent.
I know this question was asked before, and I checked every solution in those threads, and none seemed to work. Exporting as OpenEXR or using Cycles does not help either.
I'm using Blender 4.2.2 LTS. The VDB was exported from EmberGen.




difficult to say. Can you share a simplified project to take a look?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background/44148#44148
