# Is it possible to export emission as a png texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, emission

So I made a mesh, very simple and added emission to it. I wanted to make neon effect and now I am struggling how to export it as a texture. Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: Not as a PNG with transparency. You need a format that supports associated alpha channel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the Glare node to output transparent instead of Black background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background) and [render semi-transparent volume with cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles)

Comment: Why do you want to export the texture? Later use in Blender, game engine?

Comment: @Bruno latter i want to use my mesh in spark ar

Comment: I think it depends on what shading feature Spark AR provides. I doubt that it provides bloom effect like you want  so even if you somewhat bake the bloom effect in a texture, it will all be flat when applied to your Spark AR model. You would need to be creative and simulate the bloom for example with some outer semi transparent tube around the inner emission one.... even then good luck to render the same effect!