# Whenever I render my file it doesn't looks completely different from the preview render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

`[![enter code here][1]][1]`I was working on an explosion simulation and when I tried to render it, it came out really low quality and the emitters were low.  I don't know a ton of the technical stuff, but here are some pictures. [image][image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show some of your settings in the outliner and their visibility. Render Settings panel may be useful as well. This may help you by giving the reader more context.  Of course Blender allows various 3D Views to be different than a final render.   The choice is yours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render semi-transparent volume with cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles)

Comment: @JachymMichal no, I already had used fire and smoke and I didn't use any transparent shaders.

Comment: I will try to do what you said first though

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I'll add a picture of the render settings