# EEVE Bloom not visible with alpha after saving the render as a file

Tags: rendering, export, eevee-render-engine, transparency

Render preview gives the desired result:

[image]

After saving it to a .png file:

[image]

Blooms dissapears completly.

Saving as a .tif produces the same result

Using .bmp brings the bloom back, but the transparency is gone

Is there a setting I'm missing? Or is this a issue with the file types I used?

Comment: Can you add your .blend into your question: https://blend-exchange.com/? .png would work for alpha-type images

Comment: The PNG format will not work for what you want to do. Use EXR

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41598/92768

Comment: @susu It works, thanks , but I don't see the option to mark your comment as an answer